# Laravel 4 - Custom Session Handler

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking to use my own session handler in Laravel 4. Where could I extend Laravel 4 sessions so I can use my own specified class to read/write/delete data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Laravel docs on extending Laravel:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending#session

You'll want to create a new ServiceProvider to boot your new Session handler early on and place it BELOW the original SessionServiceProvider reference in your app config.
Ex.

```
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MySessionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register my custom service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerMySessionHandler();
    }

   /**
     * Register your session manager instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerMySessionHandler()
    {
        $this->app->bindShared('mysession', function($app)
        {
            return new MySessionHandler($app);
        });
    }
```

Look at Illuminate/Session/SessionServiceProvider.php and the ServiceProvider docs (http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers) if you need more info.

Write your Session class:

```
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface {

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName) {}
    public function close() {}
    public function read($sessionId) {}
    public function write($sessionId, $data) {}
    public function destroy($sessionId) {}
    public function gc($lifetime) {}

}
```

Then you can extend the Session class using the Session::extend() method (I believe this goes in your start file, but don't quote me on that):

```
Session::extend('mysession', function($app)
{
    return new MySessionHandler;
});
```

Once the session driver has been registered, you should use the `mysession` driver in your app/config/session.php configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, create and place sessionpayload.php in application/libraries folder and extend like this:

```
class Sessionpayload extends \Laravel\Session\Payload {

//stuff

}
```

Then, create and place session.php in application/libraries folder and extend like that:

```
class Session extends \Laravel\Session {


public static function start($driver)
{
    static::$instance = new Sessionpayload(static::factory($driver));
}

}
```

Then, you should comment out below line or you can change if you use namespace for your class:

```
'Session'       => 'Laravel\\Session',
```

in application/config/application.php .

Comment: Does this work in Laravel 4. I don't see the application or libraries folder in Laravel 4.

Comment: You need to use [composer](http://getcomposer.org) to install the framework (laravel/framework). You likely have just got the skeleton app (laravel/laravel).

Comment: If composer is not the point of confusion, then i beleive the answer your looking for is that you can simply make a library directory. Best case is to make a library directory and set up PSR-0 auto loading to it via the composer.json file.